# Ромбовидные элементы галереи и двухцветная заливка чисел css

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Какое наиболее оптимальное решение для реализации плитки галереи в виде ромбов, как на рисунке ниже, моим решением является два rotate, но тогда приходится задавать отрицательные margin, что-то вроде, но масштаб нужен desktop:

```css
.work-portfolio__items {
    margin: 0 70px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
}

.work-portfolio__item {
    width: 260px;
    height: 260px;
    margin: -20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-color: #212121;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 12.5px;
}

.work-portfolio__item::before {
    content: '+';
    font-size: 20px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -9px;
    left: calc(100% - 42px);
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.work-portfolio__item::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: calc(100% - 35px);
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #cd2929;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-portfolio__items">
  <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
      <p>Vinyl record</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
      <p>3D Wooden Logo</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
      <p>Hard Cover Book</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
      <p>macbook-air600</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
      <p>Silver Stamping</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
      <p>T-Shirt MockUp</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
      <p>Fashion Glasses</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
      <p>picjumbo</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
      <p>Embossed Leather</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
      <p>Billboard</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
      <p>macbook pro</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
      <p>Vintage Car</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
      <p>madebyvadim</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

[image: Галерея]

Во втором случае, как лучше сделать, чтобы было 2 цвета у числа при том, что число находится на разных цветовых background? из вариантов в голову приходит: просто вставить картинку, использовать каким-то образом градиент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7):

Вариант clip-path

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}

.work-portfolio__items {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-width: 600px;
    
}
.work-portfolio__items ul{
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
}
.work-portfolio__items ul > li{
    list-style: none;
    width: 50%;
}
.work-portfolio__items ul > li:nth-child(3n + 3){
    width: 100%;
    margin: -120px 0;
}

.work-portfolio__item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 260px;
    height: 260px;    
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #212121;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 12.5px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.work-portfolio__item::before {
    content: '+';
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -17.5px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #CD2929;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .work-portfolio__items ul > li:nth-child(3n + 3){
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .work-portfolio__items ul > li,
    .work-portfolio__items ul > li:nth-child(3n + 3){
        width: 100%;       
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="work-portfolio__items">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
        <p>Vinyl record</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
        <p>3D Wooden Logo</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
        <p>Hard Cover Book</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
        <p>macbook-air600</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
        <p>Silver Stamping</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
        <p>T-Shirt MockUp</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
        <p>Fashion Glasses</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
        <p>picjumbo</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
        <p>Embossed Leather</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
        <p>Billboard</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
        <p>macbook pro</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="work-portfolio__item">
        <p>Vintage Car</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Цифры

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}

.rhombs {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.rhomb {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 25px auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #CD2929;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.rhomb:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    bottom: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.rhomb__inner {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: #CD2929;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rhomb__number {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #CD2929;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.rhomb__number--2 {
    color: #fff;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="rhombs">
    <div class="rhomb">
        <div class="rhomb__number">62</div>
        <div class="rhomb__inner">
            <div class="rhomb__number rhomb__number--2">
                62
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rhomb">
        <div class="rhomb__number">100</div>
        <div class="rhomb__inner">
            <div class="rhomb__number rhomb__number--2">
                100
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rhomb">
        <div class="rhomb__number">15</div>
        <div class="rhomb__inner">
            <div class="rhomb__number rhomb__number--2">
                15
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ✅Спасибо за решение! очень полезно узнать такое :-)

Comment: Первый вариант не соответствует макету, получается просто сетка, а не "шахматная" плитка

Answer (score 2):

Сделаем ромбы через обычный квадрат с повёрнутым псевдоэлементом.

Для адекватных отступов, чтобы эти ромбы не налазили друг на друга применяем формулу `a × (√2 - 1) / 2`, где `a` — это высота и ширина квадрата. Вычислим константу `(√2 - 1) / 2 ≈ 0,2071067811865475`.

Демонстрация самого принципа:

```css
.rhomb {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  
  /* смещение чтобы не налезать на другие элементы */
  /* это аналогичино margin: calc(100px * (1.414213562373095 - 1) / 2)); */
  margin: calc(100px * 0.2071067811865475);
  
  /* стили для того чтобы элемент не занимал всю строку */
  /* и для центрирования текста вертикально и горизонтально */
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rhomb:after {
  content: "";
  
  /* абсолтное позиционирование */
  position: absolute;
  
  /* занимаем столько же места, сколько контейнер */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  /* окрашиваем в нужный цвет */
  background-color: red;
  
  /* вращаем на 45 градусов */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  
  /* отрицательный z-index, чтобы не перекрывать контент главного блока */
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
<div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
<div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
<div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
<div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
<div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
<div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
<div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
<div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
```

Следующая проблема в том, что я не знаю как расположить элементы (и, видимо, это невозможно) как на макете адаптивно и не используя JavaScript. Поэтому покажу демонтрация для фиксированной разметки для трёх ромбов в ширину. Эту же разметку можно чуть модифицировать и использовать JavaScript. Надо только на `resize` убирать и навешивать `rhomb--even-row`.

```css
.rhombs-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rhombs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* максимум 3 ромба учитывая также margin 10px */
  width: calc(3 * 100px * 1.414213562373095 + 60px);
  outline: 2px dotted gray;
}

.rhomb {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  
  /* смещение чтобы не налезать на другие элементы */
  /* это аналогичино margin: calc(100px * (1.414213562373095 - 1) / 2) + 10px); */
  margin: calc(100px * 0.2071067811865475 + 10px);
  
  /* стили для того чтобы элемент не занимал всю строку */
  /* и для центрирования текста вертикально и горизонтально */
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rhomb:after {
  content: "";
  
  /* абсолтное позиционирование */
  position: absolute;
  
  /* занимаем столько же места, сколько контейнер */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  /* окрашиваем в нужный цвет */
  background-color: red;
  
  /* вращаем на 45 градусов */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  
  /* отрицательный z-index, чтобы не перекрывать контент главного блока */
  z-index: -1;
}

/* арифметика смещения элементов чётных строк */
.rhomb--even-row {
  margin-top: calc(-100px / 2 * 1.414213562373095 + 20px);
  margin-left: calc(100px / 2 * (1.414213562373095 + 0.2071067811865475 * 2) + 20px);
  margin-bottom: calc(-100px / 2 * 1.414213562373095 + 20px);
}

.rhomb--even-row + .rhomb--even-row {
  margin-left: calc(100px / 2 * 0.2071067811865475 + 20px);
}-
```

```html
<div class="rhombs-container">
  <div class="rhombs">
    <div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
    <div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
    <div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
    <div class="rhomb rhomb--even-row">Это же ромб</div>
    <div class="rhomb rhomb--even-row">Это же ромб</div>
    <div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
    <div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
    <div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
    <div class="rhomb rhomb--even-row">Это же ромб</div>
    <div class="rhomb rhomb--even-row">Это же ромб</div>
    <div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
    <div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
    <div class="rhomb">Это же ромб</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Для чисел также подойдёт данная техника в сочении с градиентами (не включая случай с `MARKETING`, `62`. Демонстрация:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.rhombs-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rhombs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* максимум 3 ромба учитывая также margin 10px */
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.rhomb {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  
  /* смещение чтобы не налезать на другие элементы */
  /* это аналогичино margin: calc(100px * (1.414213562373095 - 1) / 2) + 10px); */
  margin: calc(100px * 0.2071067811865475 + 10px);
  
  /* стили для того чтобы элемент не занимал всю строку */
  /* и для центрирования текста вертикально и горизонтально */
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  /* Стили для чисел */
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.rhomb:after {
  content: "";
  
  /* абсолтное позиционирование */
  position: absolute;
  
  /* занимаем столько же места, сколько контейнер */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  /* окрашиваем в нужный цвет */
  border: 1px solid #cd2a2a;
  
  /* вращаем на 45 градусов */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  
  /* отрицательный z-index, чтобы не перекрывать контент главного блока */
  z-index: -1;
}

.rhomb:nth-child(1):after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #cd2a2a 95%, transparent 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(2):after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #cd2a2a 77%, transparent 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(3):after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #cd2a2a 99%, transparent 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(4):after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #cd2a2a 62%, transparent 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(5):after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #cd2a2a 85%, transparent 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="rhombs-container">
  <div class="rhombs">
    <div class="rhomb">95</div>
    <div class="rhomb">77</div>
    <div class="rhomb">99</div>
    <div class="rhomb">62</div>
    <div class="rhomb">85</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Для установки градиента (случай `MARKETING`, `62`) на шрифте ромба можно прибегнуть к комбинации свойств `-webkit-background-clip: text;` и  `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;` (ну и разумеется самого градиента). Но и тут нам не обойтись без дополнительных градиентов и математики. Результат:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


.rhombs-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rhombs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* максимум 3 ромба учитывая также margin 10px */
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.rhomb {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  /* смещение чтобы не налезать на другие элементы */
  /* это аналогичино margin: calc(100px * (1.414213562373095 - 1) / 2) + 10px); */
  margin: calc(100px * 0.2071067811865475);
  /* стили для того чтобы элемент не занимал всю строку */
  /* и для центрирования текста вертикально и горизонтально */
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Стили для чисел */
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  
  /* текст принимает картинку фона */
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.rhomb:after {
  content: "";
  
  /* абсолтное позиционирование */
  position: absolute;
  
  /* занимаем столько же места, сколько контейнер */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  /* добавляем границу */
  border: 1px solid #cd2a2a;
  
  /* вращаем на 45 градусов */
  transform: rotate(45deg);

  /* отрицательный z-index, чтобы не перекрывать контент главного блока */
  z-index: -1;
}

.rhomb:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, currentColor calc(95% + (95% - 50%) * 0.414213562373095), #cd2a2a 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, currentColor calc(77% + (77% - 50%) * 0.414213562373095), #cd2a2a 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, currentColor calc(99% + (99% - 50%) * 0.414213562373095), #cd2a2a 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, currentColor calc(62% + (62% - 50%) * 0.414213562373095), #cd2a2a 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(5) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, currentColor calc(85% + (85% - 50%) * 0.414213562373095), #cd2a2a 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(6) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, currentColor calc(25% + (25% - 50%) * 0.414213562373095), #cd2a2a 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(7) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, currentColor calc(35% + (35% - 50%) * 0.414213562373095), #cd2a2a 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(8) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, currentColor calc(45% + (45% - 50%) * 0.414213562373095), #cd2a2a 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(9) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, currentColor calc(55% + (55% - 50%) * 0.414213562373095), #cd2a2a 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(1):after {
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, #cd2a2a 95%, transparent 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(2):after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #cd2a2a 77%, transparent 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(3):after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #cd2a2a 99%, transparent 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(4):after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #cd2a2a 62%, transparent 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(5):after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #cd2a2a 85%, transparent 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(6):after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #cd2a2a 25%, transparent 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(7):after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #cd2a2a 35%, transparent 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(8):after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #cd2a2a 45%, transparent 0);
}

.rhomb:nth-child(9):after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #cd2a2a 55%, transparent 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="rhombs-container">
  <div class="rhombs">
    <div class="rhomb">95</div>
    <div class="rhomb">77</div>
    <div class="rhomb">99</div>
    <div class="rhomb">62</div>
    <div class="rhomb">85</div>
    <div class="rhomb">25</div>
    <div class="rhomb">35</div>
    <div class="rhomb">45</div>
    <div class="rhomb">55</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Небольшая заметка:

Я использую `0` как ступенях градиентов, чтобы не дублировать предыдущие значения, так как по [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#color-stop-syntax) ступенька градиента не может быть меньше предыдущего значения.

> If a color-stop has a position that is less than the specified position of any color-stop before it in the list, set its position to be equal to the largest specified position of any color-stop before it.